# MathGame Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make a Math game, but when set property on start game.

```
//if we click on the start/reset`enter code here`
document.getElementById("startreset").onclick = function() {
    //if we are playing
    if(playing == true) {
        location.reload(); // reload page
    } else{ //if we are not playing
        //set score to 0enter code here
```

In console I get MathGameJS.js:5 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'onclick' of null, I appreciate any help.

Comment: looks like you don't have a element with ID `startreset` when this script runs. We'll need to see your HTML, but either you've made a typo with the ID, or this script is in the `head` when it should be at the end of the `body`.

Comment: Can you show us your html too, my guess is that you have a typo in the id of your button. It has to be <input type="button" id="startreset">Reset</input>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem seems to be you are executing the script before the element is loaded.

I assume this script is added in the MathGame.js file which is added before the DOM is created.

The solution here is to execute the script after the DOM is ready like:

```
window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById("startreset").onclick=function(){
        //your code
    }
}
```

All JavaScript code which deals with DOM elements like the one above has to be executed only after the DOM is loaded.